# Select last Order state from Orders

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables:

orders:

```
id_order    id_customer    
1           1              
2           2              
3           1
```

orders_history

```
id_history  id_order    id_order_state    date_add
1           1           1                 2010-01-01 00:00:00
2           1           2                 2010-01-02 00:00:00
3           1           3                 2010-01-03 00:00:00
4           2           2                 2010-05-01 00:00:00
5           2           3                 2011-05-02 00:00:00
6           3           1                 2011-05-03 00:00:00
7           3           2                 2011-06-01 00:00:00
```

order_state

```
id_order_state    name
1                 New
2                 Sent
3                 Rejected
4                 ...
```

How to get all order_id's where last id_order_state of that order (by last I mean this with MAX(id_history) or MAX(date_add)) is not equal 1 or 3?

Comment: Can you post the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what he's after is what orders are complete... ie their final status, not those that are exclusive of the 1 and 3 specifically.  The first pre-query should be the max ID regardless of the status code

```
select 
      orders.*
   from
      ( select oh.id_order, 
               max( oh.id_history ) LastID_HistoryPerOrder
           from
               orders_history oh
           group by
               oh.id_order ) PreQuery
      join orders_history oh2
         on PreQuery.ID_Order = oh2.id_order
         AND PreQuery.LastID_HistoryPerOrder = oh2.id_history
         AND NOT OH2.id_order_state IN (1, 3)   <<== THIS ELIMINATES 1's & 3's from result set
      join Orders                               <<= NOW, anything left after above ^ is joined to orders
         on PreQuery.ID_Order = Orders.ID_Order
```

Just to re-show YOUR data... I've marked the last SEQUENCE (ID_History) per ORDER... This is what the PREQUERY is going to return...

```
id_history  id_order    id_order_state    date_add
  1           1          1                2010-01-01 00:00:00
  2           1          2                2010-01-02 00:00:00   
**3           1          3                2010-01-03 00:00:00

  4           2          2                2010-05-01 00:00:00   
**5           2          3                2011-05-02 00:00:00

  6           3          1                2011-05-03 00:00:00   
**7           3          2                2011-06-01 00:00:00
```

The "PreQuery" will result with the following subset

```
ID_Order   LastID_HistoryPerOrder (ID_History)
1          3  (state=3)  THIS ONE WILL BE SKIPPED IN FINAL RESULT
2          5  (state=3)  THIS ONE WILL BE SKIPPED IN FINAL RESULT
3          7  (state=2)
```

Now, the result of this is then re-joined back to order history on just these two elements... yet adds the criteria to EXCLUDE the 1,3 entries for "order state".

In this case,

```
   1 would be rejected as its state = 3 (sequence #3), 
   2 would be rejected since its last history is state = 3 (sequence #5).  
   3 would be INCLUDED since its state = 2 (sequence #7)
```

Finally, all that joined to the orders will result with ONE ID, and nicely match up with the orders table on the Order_ID alone and get the desired results.

Comment: @DRapp but for id_order = 2 it should return 3 as last id_order_state. For id_order = 3 it should return 2.

Comment: @dario, please re-review this answer.  I've change the prequery result column name to help clarify what I originally meant from "LastSequence".  Its now "LastID_HistoryPerOrder".  Additionally, in the final query, I have two   <<==   comment lines that should be removed.  These are to help clarify WHEN the 1's and 3's are stripped out.

Comment: @DRapp Please have a look at my post with results of your querry.

Comment: @Dario, you mis-posted my query in two parts...  The NOT IN clause should have been NOT IN oh2.id_order_state IN (1,3)... you had just (3).  Next, the group by of the INNER PRE QUERY... You have the order by the HISTORY ID... Nope.. Just the ID_ORDER and you'll get what you are expecting...  I actually tried it with your data and got what was expected... one record... order #3

Answer (score 4):

```
select oh.id_history, oh.id_order, oh.id_order_state, oh.date_add
from (
    select id_order, max(date_add) as MaxDate
    from orders_history
    where id_order_state not in (1, 3)
    group by id_order 
) ohm
inner join orders_history oh on ohm.id_order = oh.id_order 
    and ohm.MaxDate = oh.date_add
```

Comment: For reference, this type of problem is often referred to as the "groupwise max" problem.

Comment: @TehShrike Strange but I'm not getting proper result: i think, that there is problem with getting MAX date. The same with @Tom H. answer.

Comment: @dario what is the data type of the `date_add` column?

Comment: @dario - I can't help you then, either something is profoundly broken, or you are querying a different db/table than you think...

Comment: @RedFilter I can give you phpmydamin access to test db if you have some time.

Comment: @RedFilter, check my answer... I think it was a mis-interpretation / clarification of the original question...

Comment: @RedFilter: I mean select max(date_add) from orders_history works but whole subquery doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id_order
FROM
    Orders_History OH1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders_History OH2 ON
    OH2.id_order = OH1.id_order AND
    OH2.is_order_state IN (1, 3) AND
    OH2.date_add >= OH1.date_add
WHERE
    OH2.id_order IS NULL
```

Comment: For example for set having: date_add: 2011-05-11 22:36:20 and 2011-04-16 23:21:24 it gives me the second as max date and then wrong id_state

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by it, but if you were trying to use the LEFT JOIN method of finding extremal values, then I think you got it a bit wrong. It should be `...ON OH2.id_order = OH1.id_order AND OH2.date_add > OH1.date_add WHERE OH1.is_order_state NOT IN (1, 3) AND OH2.id_order IS NULL`.

Comment: @andriy-m You have right! @Tom-h please correct your answer like andriy-m said and it will be finished :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "answer for my question" because I need to post results of your queries. So.

Unfortunately not all of your answers guys works. Let's prepare test environment:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_history` (
`id_order_history` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_order_state` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_history`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id_order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2;

INSERT INTO `order_history` 
(`id_order_history`, `id_order`, `id_order_state`,     `date_add`) VALUES 
(1,1,1,'2011-01-01 00:00:00'),
(2,1,2,'2011-01-01 00:10:00'),
(3,1,3,'2011-01-01 00:20:00'),
(4,2,1,'2011-02-01 00:00:00'),
(5,2,2,'2011-02-01 00:25:01'),
(6,2,3,'2011-02-01 00:25:59'),
(7,3,1,'2011-03-01 00:00:01'),
(8,3,2,'2011-03-01 00:00:02'),
(9,3,3,'2011-03-01 00:01:00'),
(10,3,2,'2011-03-02 00:00:01');
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id_order`, `id_customer`) VALUES 
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4),
(5,5),
(6,6),
(7,7);
COMMIT;
```

Now, lets select Last/Max State for each Order, so let's run simple query:

```
 select id_order, max(date_add) as MaxDate
 from `order_history`
 group by id_order
```

this gives us PROPER results, no rocket science right now:

```
id_order         MaxDate
---------+-------------------
1         2011-01-01 00:20:00  //last order_state=3
2         2011-02-01 00:25:59  //last order_state=3
3         2011-03-02 00:00:01  //last order_state=2
```

Now for simplicity, lest **change** our queries to get Orders **where Last State is not equal 3**.

**We're expecting to get one row result with id_order = 3**.

So let's test our queries:

QUERY 1 made by *RedFilter*:

```
select oh.id_order, oh.id_order_state, oh.date_add
from (
    select id_order, max(date_add) as MaxDate
    from `order_history`
    where id_order_state not in (3)
    group by id_order
) ohm
inner join `order_history` oh on ohm.id_order = oh.id_order 
and ohm.MaxDate = oh.date_add
```

Result:

```
id_order    id_order_state    date_add
-------------------------------------------------
1           2                 2011-01-01 00:10:00
2           2                 2011-02-01 00:25:01
3           2                 2011-03-02 00:00:01
```

So it's **not true**

QUERY 2 made by *Tom H.*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OH1.id_order
FROM order_history OH1
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_history OH2 ON
  OH2.id_order = OH1.id_order AND
  OH2.id_order_state NOT IN (3) AND
  OH2.`id_order_history` >= OH1.`id_order_history`
WHERE
  OH2.id_order IS NULL
```

Result:

```
id_order
--------
1
2
```

So it's **not true**

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Andriy M. comment we have **proper solution**. It's a modification of Tom H. query all should looks as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
OH1.id_order
FROM
  order_history OH1
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_history OH2 ON
  OH2.id_order = OH1.id_order
AND OH2.date_add > OH1.date_add 
WHERE OH1.id_order_state NOT IN (3) AND OH2.id_order IS NULL
```

**EDIT 2:**

QUERY 3 made by *DRapp*:

```
select
  distinct orders.`id_order`
from
  ( select oh.id_order,
           max( oh.id_order_history ) LastID_HistoryPerOrder
       from
           order_history oh
       group by
           oh.id_order ) PreQuery
  join order_history oh2
     on PreQuery.id_order = oh2.id_order
     AND PreQuery.LastID_HistoryPerOrder = oh2.id_order_history
     AND NOT oh2.id_order_state IN (1,3)  
join orders                              
  on PreQuery.id_order = orders.id_order
```

Result:

```
id_order
--------
3
```

So it's finally **true**